# performing multiple levels of aggregation functions in a query without sub query

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I want to perform multiple levels of aggregation in a query without the use of a sub query.

Suppose

There exists fields, ***field_c***, ***field_r***, ***time***, ***val***, such that for each ***field_c*** there exists N ***field_r***, ***vals***.
For each ***time*** there exists m ***field_c***

I would like to get the SUM of the MAX of a ***val*** for each ***field_c***, COUNT of DISTINCT ***field_c***, in group ***time***.

I've created a simple example which can be viewed link [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dd669/10) which uses a subquery but how can it be done without one

Comment: Please show the actual tables with some test data and your expected output. You are very familiar with the problem. Us, not so much, so we need these things. An [SQLFiddle would be nice](http://sqlfiddle.com). Your current query, whether it gives the correct results or not, would be helpful as well.

Comment: there is an sql fiddle, in the last line the link was provided the blue word 'here', and sorry but it's implied that it gives correct results if im asking for a version without a sub query

Comment: thanks - it helps us to understand what we have to work with and what you want.